# Return value from Object Array in Angular 7

Tags: angular6, angular7

I am relatively new to Angular, but I have a lot going on. Let me explain. I have an array of objects and a successful service running as shown below.
[array of Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xptd4.png)

I have a input created as a search that is using the ngx-bootstrap TypeAheadModule so I can show typeahead values in the search. This is successful if I use a hard coded string array.

The html markup for the component shown below based on that ngx-bootstrap documentation.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selected"
[typeahead]="points"
class="form-control">
```

This [typeahead] attribute looks to only accept a string array.

So here is my issue. I have an array of objects from my service, but I only need the name value from each object to fill what will become a string array for my search. I have been all over the internet looking for the best way to retrieve just a value from my array. I feel like I am missing some extremely simple.

Below is where I currently left it. I have my api call for points loading into a point array until I can figure out how to access the values inside the array.

```
points: Point[] = [];  

 this.service.getPoints().subscribe(response=> {
  this.points = response as Point[]
});
```

This current returns [Object Object] in my TypeAhead. How can I access the values into my array and return them as a string array?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a small section on the ngx-bootstrap documentation. There is an additional attribute 'typeaheadOptionField' that lets you select the field out of a more complex object array.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. I think you missed a div with **ngFor**

```
  <div *ngFor="let point as points; let i of index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="point[i]"
    [typeahead]="point"
    class="form-control">
  </div>
```

your trying to print `points` array directly, I hope this approach will solve your issue.

Comment: I did try this previously. It just breaks up my input field into several input fields equal with the array and does not return the items in the array.